# What to do with not so de-husked Carafa 3 when brewing black AIPA?

Tags: all-grain, specialty-grains

I bought what was supposed to be Carafa 3 special. But it has a lot of husk. I don't want roasted bitterness and acridicity in this brew. What should I do?

Today is the brew day and I needed to go with what I had. So I steeped 400g (grounded to about 200-300 microns) in cold water all night. Today I used 150 microns filtering bag and discarded solids. Resulting liquid is thick, black, opaque and hardly bitter. I was planning to add it at the end of mash, to convert leftovers, if any, and to filter it with the rest of my wort. But now, when I know there was husk in it, I doubt if it is the best plan. Should I rather pour it into filtering tun? Or add at the end of the boil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still want other answers.

I needed to go with this brew, so here is what I figured would be safest.

1. I let filtered black extract sit for few hours undisturbed. Leftover solids settled down at the bottom.
2. Poured liquid, now clear reddish when observed against strong light, to recirculation tun.
3. I skipped mash-out, leaving enzymes in my wort (hey, it's supposed to be dry beer anyway)
4. I started filtering.
5. Before beginning of recirculation, I heated black extract + wort mixture to 65 degrees Celsius, to make sure any leftover starch will convert.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're good, if you're cold steep gave you the color and flavor you wanted.

Just a note. Tannins give the bitter astringency and are only extracted from husks when ph is above 6.0 AND temp is 170° or above. So on that part they could have been full husk and mashed, but you would have more roast flavor extraction over the cold steeping.

Also this grain as already undergone enzymatic conversion of starches during the malting process. So a steep is all that is needed for sugar extraction. There is no need for it to be in a mash, it's just generally easier to put all the grain in the mash.

Comment: Iodine test seemed to indicate starch content. Low one, and it's hard to tell for sure with all this darkness, but I'm pretty sure it got this bluish highlights.